# How to remove text in bulk and patterns with noteplad++

Tags: notepad++, purge

I'm trying to clean up this file a bit and get rid of useless lines
with notepad++. I know there was an easy way to do this but I forgot how.

Basically I want to search and remove all groups associated with (- Default)
such as below. I want to remove every uui/options/name/group/permissions
basically any player data that is in the group (- Default) but Its not
easy with the "replace" option as you can see every player has a different
name or uuid and its hard to remove in bulk since the file has over 104k lines.

- I remember it had to do with Mark options in the notepad++ *

  ```
  -> Remove       00126374-2f71-438b-b30b-2aad7da6c169:
  -> Remove     options:
  -> Remove       name: NightCorePvP
  -> Remove     group:
  -> Remove     - Default <- (Keyword)
  -> Remove     permissions:
  -> Remove     - none

    003fdb5d-b980-4761-88c8-34f0d7478755:
      options:
        name: XanderCole
      group:
      - iron
      permissions:
      - none
    0006597c-625e-4e85-a0d9-fa125f44ad5d:
      options:
        name: JugendLammy
      group:
      - Default
      permissions:
      - none  008604cc-1e71-419a-b1c9-fd79e53cabc6:
  ```

Here is an image of the file as an example on what to keep and remove
 - https://i.gyazo.com/4621d7151dbeb25a1855ffbd03f81e7d.png

Answer (score 1):

Try this find and replacement of an entire target matching group.  The trick here is to match an entire group, regardless of the field values, as long as the group is default.

**Find:**

```
\s*\w{8}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{12}:\n
\s*options:\n
\s*name: \w+\n
\s*group:\n
\s*- Default\n
\s*permissions:\n
.*\n
```

**Replace:**

```
(nothing)
```

Comment: doesnt seem to work when i add the whole thing only bits of it like the 2nd,3rd,4th line

Comment: @user3123931 I don't have your actual data in front of me, so I cannot test.  This should work based on the data you showed us.

Comment: okay this seems to work now just making sure it didn't mark any with different groups, thanks!